# Can´t connect with redux store in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Im working on a react native app. This is my screen:

NuevoTotalScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { View, ScrollView, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Controles from '../components/Controles';
import ContadorContainer from '../components/ContadorContainer';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../state/store';

class NuevoTotalScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={ styles.title }>Nuevo total</Text>

          <Controles />

          <ScrollView style={styles.scrollViewContainer}>
            <ContadorContainer />
          </ScrollView>

          <Text style={styles.total}>{ this.props.total }</Text>
                    <Button
            title="Guardar"
            color="grey"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
          />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  total: state.total,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(NuevoTotalScreen);
```

and this is my store:

store.js

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import counterReducer from './reducers/counter';
import totalReducer from './reducers/total';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  counter: counterReducer,
  total: totalReducer
});

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
  ),
);

export default store;
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Invariant violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(NuevoTotalScreen)". Either wrap the component in a
>   , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(NuevoTotalScreen)"

I uploaded my code to https://github.com/luis-sama/tp5Mobiles

Comment: Usually you would do `<Provider store={store}>< NuevoTotalScreen /> </ Provider>`. Try removing Provider from this file and use it where you user `NuevoTotalScreen`.

Comment: I use NuevoTotalScreen inside a stackNavigator. Also how would I get the state.total?

Comment: Wrap your stackNavigator with Provider. Navigators are components too. To access `state.total` you are using `connect` which connects you component to the store. That's why Provider should wrap the root component.

Comment: Don't know where to put Provider                                                                                            import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import NuevoTotalScreen from './screens/NuevoTotalScreen';
import TotalesScreen from './screens/TotalesScreen';

export default createStackNavigator({
  Totales: {
    screen: TotalesScreen
  },
  NuevoTotal: {
    screen: NuevoTotalScreen
  },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'Totales',
})

Comment: here is an article to help you. https://medium.com/async-la/a-stately-guide-to-react-navigation-with-redux-1f90c872f96e

Comment: @DexterNaru, I took a look at your code and I typically go with utilizing my root `App.js` to be at the top of the hierarchy so the Provider tag and store would be there, then I would return the class based component of `NuevoTotalScreen` from within the Provider tags that would be within `App.js`.

Comment: @DexterNaru, I just took another look at your code. Where is your `index.js` file within your `reducers/` folder? This is where you would place your `export default combineReducers()` even if you only have one reducer which is `counterReducer` although you named the file just `counter`. Within your `mapStateToProps` you have a property of `total` which should come from your `combineReducers()` that would have something like `total: counterReducer` as a key:value pair within in an object you would have in `combineReducers()` and then you would `return { total: state.total };` Ziyo mentions this

Answer (score 0):

If you have three screen in a stack navigation, then You just save them in variable and export. And then, just import that variable in Provider component.

### Example

nav.js

```
import FirstScreen from "..";
import SecondScreen from "..";
import ThirdScreen from "..";

export const FooStackNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  FirstScreen: FirstScreen,
  SecondScreen: SecondScreen,
  ThirdScreen: ThirdScreen,
})
```

Main.js (NuevoTotalScreen.js in your use case)

```
import { FooStackNavigation } from "./nav.js";

...

<Provider store={store}>
  <FooStackNavigation />
</Provider>
```

FirstScreen.js (in FooStackNavigation)

```
...

render () {
  return (
    <View><Text>{this.props.foo}</Text></View>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  foo: state.foo
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(FirstScreen);
```